# How do I get android NDK detail crash reports?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, adb, android-studio-3.0

I am debugging a huge NDK project in Android Studio, the app crashes at semingly random times with message similar to

```
A/libc: Fatal Signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x30 in fid 22993 (Thread-99505)
```

The numbers are different at times but the error is similar, and sometimes the Run tab in Android studio doesn't even show any error at all and the program just crashes with the message `Application terminated`

By looking around I have found that android should generate some kind of crash log similar to ones shown here

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash

But I do not understand how to get them, or whether there is some setting in Android Studio that allows me to view them

How do I get crash reports like these from Android Studio?

Android Studio version 3.0.1 in Apple macbook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of the Run tab, look at the Logcat. Don't set the filter to your app only. There is a good chance that you will see a stack trace, like

```
I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 351, tid: 351  >>> /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0d9f00d8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 0000af88  r1 0000a008  r2 baadf00d  r3 0d9f00d8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000004  r5 0000a008  r6 0000af88  r7 00013c44
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip 0000959c  sp be956cc8  lr 00008403  pc 0000841e  cpsr 60000030
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 0000841e  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 000083fe  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 000083f6  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #03  pc 000191ac  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #04  pc 000083ea  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #05  pc 00008458  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #06  pc 0000d362  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):
```

Android NDK includes a command [`ndk-stack`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack) that can help match the addresses with actual source files of your code, which is based on the [addr2line](https://linux.die.net/man/1/addr2line) utility in NDK toolchain.

Further instructions for understanding the stack trace: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

From comments:
You may find the 'unstripped' libraries under app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs

Comment: Hi I managed to view log messages similar to the ones you posted here after I removed all filters, and they come after the application crash message as expected. I am trying to use the ndk-stack tool now, and the page you linked to talks about $PROJECT_PATH/obj... .What is $PROJECT_PATH? I assumed it was where I made my android project (the folder that contains the app folder, build.gradle, project_name.iml, etc) , but the "obj" folder is not there. Do I need to do something to make this obj folder myself or is android studio supposed to make it?

Comment: @user13267 It might depend on your project structure, but in my projects the obj folder is typically located in app/src/main.

Comment: it's not there in my project folder. Do I need to enable some settings in android studio to get this folder created?

Comment: You may find the 'unstripped' libraries under `app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs`